# How to add custom field to view-edit post type page

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I want to add a custom field at top of the custom post type list page.
Is this possible?
Thanks in advance guys!
[image]

Comment: I think that you need to create a plugin that hooks into the lists, and add your functionality there.